# Image datatype with file name as Link

Tags: asp.net

I have this evidence field as image datatype in my table 
The user in a form enters all this data including a image file and submits it.
Now this gets stored in the Database. This field could be null

While retrieving it and displaying on a details view, 
The file-name should be displayed as a link

Here I what I have

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Evidence (if any)">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbEvidence" runat="server" OnClick="lbEvidence_Click" Text='<%# Eval("Evidence").ToString() == String.Empty ? "None" : Eval("Evidence") %>'
                        PostBackUrl='<%#"~/_UILayer1/EvidencePic.aspx?ID="+Eval("Complaint_ID") %>' > </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>
```

It shows a link button but instead of the file name it says System.Byte[]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are setting Image blob (byte array) to property Text, which is of course string. When user submits an image, you should save also its filename into DB and bind it to Text property.